# Raspberry Pi 4B won't boot, is it dead?

Tags: pi-4, hardware, boot-issues

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi world. I was in a charity shop today and I've seen a deal I couldn't resist so grabbed the Pi for 10 euro knowing full well that it could be faulty. Anyway once I got back to the workshop I plugged the Pi in to my monitor and Labists power supply (5V 3A) without an SD card. At that point all looked good Red light was solid and ACT LED was blinking 4 times then stopping for couple seconds and blinking again 4 times and the pattern repeated itself.

I got the 32GB SanDisk MicroSD that came with the kit, formatted it to FAT32 and then installed Raspberry Pi OS (32 Bit) using Raspberry Pi Imager. Inserted the MicroSD in to the RPi4 and nothing, the power LED is RED and ACT is acting crazy until it eventually stops and blinks 2-3 sometimes 4-5 times very fast every now and then.

I turned off the RPi4 and took out the SD card, I powered it on and now power is solid red and ACT is solid green (to my understanding it shouldn't be solid green without an SD card inserted).

I formatted another microSD this time SanDisk 8GB, installed OS repeated the process but it won't boot. The ACT goes crazy for first couple seconds then goes dark and blinks 1 times every 10 seconds. The light's are solid without the SD inserted.

Could anyone point me in the right direction where to even start with this? If it's firmware then what do you guys suggest? If it's hardware then I can measure all voltages etc. tomorrow at the workshop and compare them to schematics if they're available.

I would appreciate any help with this as I'm looking to put OctoPrint on it.

Forgot to add, I tried EEPROM recovery as well. The recovery is successful but this hasn't helped in anyway.

Comment: Look for the Pi4 boot sticky at raspberrypi.org/forums

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be answered by the boot sticky.

Comment: I already checked out that thread before I posted it here.

Comment: Are you saying that you get output on the monitor when you do the EEPROM recovery but when you try to boot an OS, you have no output on the monitor? You've tried both HDMI outputs?